# How to handle this situation (need to register functions with variable arguments)

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm looking for suggestion on how to handle this situation as anything I've thought of thus far does not work.

I'm working on an RPG game and am currently developing the graphical system. My graphics system consists of a series of ScreenStacks which are arranged in a particular order and then drawn.

A ScreenStack is basically just a collection of related Screens, along with a unique id and a draw order.

i.e.

```
class ScreenStack
{
//Constructors, getters/setters etc.
private:
    std::string StackName;
    int DrawPriority;
    int UID;

    bool Valid;
    bool DrawStack;
    bool UpdateStack;
    bool SendInputs;
    bool DeleteStack;
    std::vector<screen_ptr> OwnedScreens; //screen_ptr is a shared_ptr around a Screen object
};
```

A screen is a simple graphical layer responsible for visualizing some part of the game, for example there's a screen for showing the player inventory, party overview, party status in battle, enemy party, etc.

I have a screen manager that is responsible for storing the various functions for creating screen stacks (i.e. a function to create a battle stack will make a screen for the player party, the enemy party, the attack animation screen, the background, and the user interface). Each of the various screen stack creation functions needs a different set of paramters to construct it. What I'm doing now is manually adding in stack creation functions to the screen manager on an as needed basis. For instance, right now the screen manager has a function for creating the title screen stack, the start menu stack, the battle stack, the overworld stack, the tilemap stack etc.

This works, but is cumbersome and cluttered. What I'd like to be able to do is have files external from the screen manager be able to register stack creation functions with the screen manager and then I can just look up the screen creation function instead of having to add a new function to the screen manager for each stack I need to create.

I initially tried adding an `unordered_map<std::string, StackCreationFunction>` with StackCreationFunction being typedef'd as

```
boost::function<ScreenStack (Engine& engine, ScreenManager& manager, const std::string screenName, const int StackID, const std::vector<std::string>& TryToCopyScreens, ...)>
```

... was from cstdargs. The idea was that each ScreenStack would add it's own StackCreationFunction to this map. This doesn't work however as boost::function is invalid with ...

So essentially what I'm trying to do is allow external files/screens be able to register their own creation functions (that has variable arguments) with the screenmanager, and Ideally be able to do this at compile time/immediately after starting. This feels like it should be possible with the preprocessor, but I'm unsure how to do it. I'm pretty stuck here, and I really would like a better solution then adding many stack creator functions to the screen manager and cluttering it up.

Any suggestions/a better solution would be greatly appreciated, and I can provide more details if the above  was not clear enough

Thanks

Comment: Your question is admirably clear, but its quite a lot to take in.  If you don't get the answer you are looking for, I would suggest decontextualising your question so that it is shorter.  Maybe add a design-patterns and boost-function tag, as well

Comment: Would some combination of a builder design pattern with a factory design pattern suffice? So all the ScreenStacks are default constructible, but you have specialized builders with settings you can put in a file to lookup, which build the object up before returning it. A factory could be used to get the ScreenStack object you want by name (and maybe the config file for the builders to use etc.)

Answer (score 2):

> Each of the various screen stack creation functions needs a different set of paramters to construct it.

I think that's the problem here, and you need to think of an abstraction here to make your map work. After all, how are these extra arguments actually provided by the calling code? When the calling code knows which class is instantiated and can provide the arguments, you don't need the map. When not, the map is of no use, since you can't tell which arguments to provide to the stack creation function.

The most likely solution is to boost::bind away all arguments of your StackCreatorFunction that would normally go into the `...` arguments and register this bound version of your function at the unordered map, which can be freed of the `...`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that rather than having something external register into your system think about having your system call the external entity. In this case your system would locate and load a series of plugins that have specific entry points. You will need to create your variable length argument list using some convential container; either an array or data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that answers your question, but if your concern is to call various functions of different signatures from an interpreter-like code, you could (under GNU/Linux at least) use the [LibFFI](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) (a library for foreign function interface) for that.